# large collection of photos for IR software testing

Tags: testing, image-processing, opencv, datasource, image-recognition

I'm looking for large (preferably 50K+) collection of photos that I could use for testing image recognition software. So preferably photos of objects. I'm fine with album covers, movie posters or anything like that. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ImageNet database (http://www.image-net.org/ - seems to be down at the time I'm writing this, but i think that's temporary) is something you could look into, if it comes back up. It has literally millions of labeled images, seperated into a hierarchy of classes (you don't have to download the complete set).

Comment: It's up and running right now, seems pretty useful. I'll take closer look at it on Monday.

Answer (score -3):

What about a google search like [this](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1649&bih=948&as_st=y&tbs=isz%3alt,islt%3asvga&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=hammer%20OR%20car%20OR%20football%20OR%20book%20OR%20screen%20OR%20telephone%20OR%20man%20OR%20hand%20OR%20plane&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)?

Another google search let me find [this one](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~aloi/). Lots of objects there.

Comment: not really useful, as I won't manually download 50K+ images, and I don't see any decent way to script it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'decent way'? Just look at the html response and you'll find a lot of imageurl=<daUrl>&amp; . Just pick the URL and load the data.

Comment: I didn't, but I perfectly understand the downvote. Google results aren't neccessarily containing the objects you searched for, you don't have labels, etc etc ... all in all, not a useful answer.

Comment: This is to test an image recognition software so '*Google results aren't neccessarily containing the objects you searched for*' could be a feature.